# Issue with cookie and this google analitics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

```
`<script type="text/plain" data-cookiecategory="cookie">
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-x', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>`
```

Uncaught TypeError: ga is not a function

Note: If I reload the page it will work

If I insert with this tag  instead of this  is working perfectly, but I need the second one to accept the cookies.

any idea of what I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Yogi has a good point there. It's gonna be deprecated soon.

Otherwise, your issue is that you're attempting to execute code that relies on the analytics.js library. Judging from how you're having this code in , it's executed before third party libraries are loaded whenever they're not cached.

Try adding defer to your snippet, but it's a wonky fix. A better solution would be removing this altogether and reimplementing it in GTM, which I would strongly suggest you doing. Well, or adding a listener to the analytics.js being loaded if you're good at JS.